# g++ #include file not found compiler error

Tags: c++, boost, terminal, makefile

I'm currently trying to simply link a file called main.cpp with boost in order to do asio(asynchronous input and output).  I'm using a makefile in order to compile the C++ code into executable form.  However, despite using the -I modifier on my terminal command in Mac OS X, it still cannot find the appropriate directory to search in.  Here is my code in Main

```
#include <asio.hpp>

int main(){
  return 1;
}
```

and here is the makefile command that I am using

```
all:
g++ -Iboost_1_60_0/boost/ -o main main.cpp
```

In my file structure, boost_1_60_0, main.cpp, and makefile are all on the top level, where asio is in the folder boost which is in the folder boost_1_60_0.  I'm very confused about this and any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT: Full error is

```
1 error generated.
make: *** [all] Error 1
iMats-2:SerialC++ wfehrnstrom$ make
g++ -Iboost_1_60_0 -o main main.cpp
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'asio.hpp' file not found
```

Comment: I guess you don't see the whole path, cd into the boost dir from terminal and run `pwd`.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` Why? Not only is this an antiquated header from C, but you're not using any I/O functions.

Comment: #include <stdio.h> does serve no purpose however I wanted to include that to help pinpoint the error.  By ensuring that stdio.h could be imported, I ruled out other problems.  I will remove it from the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `-Iboost_1_60_0` (or, better still, install Boost properly so that it's found automatically under `/usr/include/`), and write `#include <boost/asio.hpp>`.

The include directives *inside* Boost itself will assume this form, so…

BTW, this has nothing to do with exceptions. Presumably it's a compiler error you've seen.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  The compile-time error on the #include statement has been solved but I now get an even weirder error: undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init2 in main-f49282.o
      boost::asio::error::get_system_category() in main-f49282.o
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in main-f49282.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init1 in main-f49282.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Comment: Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: @wfehrn: Yes, you forgot to link the library.